# Is 'Polymathness' an acceptable noun?

Tags: nouns

If it's not, what else makes better?

To emphasize the target meaning: I mean the state of being a polymath.

Comment: It is a legitimate formation.  It is not a [*proper noun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun) in the sense of that term when it refers to names of people (like "Ahmed").

Comment: Oops. I really felt 'proper noun' means something special. Instead, I mean acceptable, or legitimate like what you've stated. Thanks.

Comment: polymathism, bilingualism, polyglottism, rather than ness.

Comment: Define *acceptable*. To whom?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because two fairly high-end U.S. dictionaries don't provide a separate entry (with definition) for the form of _polymath_ that means "the state of being a polymath." Therefore, in my opinion, this doesn't qualify as a general-reference question.

Answer (score 1):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) suggests that the state of being a polymath is termed *polymathy*, although it doesn't provide a separate entry for that term:

> **polymath** (1621) : a person of encyclopedic learning — **polymath** or **polymathic** *adj* — **polymathy** *n*

*The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2011) agrees:

> **polymath** *n.* A person of great or varied learning. ... —**polymath**, **polymathic**, *adj.* —**polymathy** *n.*

*Webster's Third New International Dictionary* (1986) does have a separate entry for *polymathy*:

> **polymathy** *n* the character or attainments of a polymath : encyclopedic learning {scorn for mere *polymathy* —G.W. Johnson}